# Converting columns to nvarchar inside variable declaration

Tags: sql, casting

I declare my variable as:

```
Declare @listOfYears nvarchar(max)
set @listOfYears = 'some text to start '
select @listOfYears = 
@listOfYears  + 
CAST(Year as nvarchar(4)) from YearsTable Where Year > 2000
+ ' some text after each year'
```

and get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'some text after each year' to data type int.

Edit: I just realized it's trying to add the 'some text after each year' to the '2000' in the 'Where' part of the query, and I need it to bee added after each line of the select query.

How do I make sure it adds the 'some text after each year' after each line of the result the select query returns and not to where 'where' part of the query?

I need @listOfYears variable to be:
'Some text to start 2001 some text after each year 2002 some text after each year 2003 some text after each year'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I executed your script but the problem is in the last part of your query, what you put after the WHERE condition (+ 'some text after each year')

I commented your last row ant it works:

```
Declare @listOfYears nvarchar(max)
set @listOfYears = 'some text to start '
select @listOfYears = 
@listOfYears  + 
CAST(Years as nvarchar(4)) from #yeartable Where Years > 2000
--+ 'some text after each year' -> row commented because is not correct add text after WHERE

select @listOfYears
```

In this way it works. Maybe you wanted to do that?

```
create table #yeartable (years int)
insert into #yeartable values (2000)


Declare @listOfYears nvarchar(max)
set @listOfYears = 'some text to start '
select @listOfYears = 
@listOfYears  + 
CAST(Years as nvarchar(4)) + ' some text after each year' from #yeartable Where Years > 2000

select @listOfYears
```